# Populate newly created columns for older database records in production?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I have stumbled upon a scenario that I believe is quite common but I don't hear about it very often.

So, I have a situation where I have extended my existing database table with another column, which is supposed to store very specific unique value for each customer. When I create new records in the system, that column will be populated and it works fine.
However, the issue now is that I have a bunch of older records that existed before this column was introduced, and they are empty, and as a result the code cannot execute correctly.

I'm really curious how this issue is typically solved ? In order to populate this column with valid values my only solution would be to run a script that would extract the values from one table and insert it into another, but is there maybe a more standardized solution ?

I am using spring boot and flyway for db migrations, would be great if there's a solution related to that.

Answer (score 1):

when that happend i just make a new version of the flyway migration package like :

```
 migration/V4__add_column1_table1
 migration/V5__fix_table1_column1_nulls
```

and inside the script run :

```
update table1 set column1 = 'Default Value' where column1 is null;
```

Maybe there exists more clean ways but that fix worked for me.

Comment: I could do that, but in my case 'default value', won't get me far, I need the correct value inside that record in order to continue execution.

Comment: if the correct value cant be executed by a single query, like update or select into, you sould update the old table programmatically with one async job with all your business logic, that is the ugly and long way, but with legacy apps its common.

Comment: I see now that flyway supports java based migrations. Perhaps that's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it in 3 steps using the flyway script. This works in Postgres.

1. Add the new column without the unique constraint

   ```
   alter table my_table add column my_new_column varchar(255);
   ```
2. Populate the table with data from another table.

The sub-query below can be updated as needed to pull data from another table

```
   update my_table m set my_new_column=sq.value from (select value, foreign_id from another_table) as sq where sq.foreign_id=m.id;
```

Similarly you can calculate the new value of the new column using existing columns of the current table:

```
   update my_table set my_new_column=concat(existing_column_1, existing_column_2);
```

3. Add the unique constraint:

   ```
   alter table my_table add constraint my_table_my_new_column_uk unique (my_new_column);
   ```